# Encontrar el segundo hashtag con REGEX

Tags: regex, google-data-studio

trabajo normalmente con Google data studio , cree un campo llamado "primerhashtag" a partir de un campo que tiene el string del texto con hashtag llamado "Message" y esta es mi función REGEXP_EXTRACT(Message,'(#+[a-zA-Z0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ʸ(*)]{1,})')
Extrae solo el primer hashtag y eso lo hace muy bien la pregunta es más de Regex si alguien me pudiera aclarar como puedo llamar al segundo o tercer hashtag mi teoría es que podría ser algo así  (#+[a-zA-Z0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ʸ(*)]{1,})(#+[a-zA-Z0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ʸ(_)]{1,}) , por supuesto lo probé y no sirve.
Agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score -1):

Usa el flag `g` (de global) en tu regex. Por ejemplo:

```js
let output = 'foofoofoofoo'.match(/foo/);
console.log('Sin flag g: ' + output);
// Output -> Sin flag g: foo

output = 'foofoofoofoo'.match(/foo/g);
console.log('Con flag g: ' + output);
// Output -> Con flag g: foo,foo,foo,foo
```